# Exporting Evernote notes to Kindle (via Gmail?)

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script, kindle, evernote

I want to export notes from one notebook I have in Evernote to my Kindle, mainly so I can access the recipes I've saved in Evernote on my Kindle without having to connect to the mobile Evernote site.
I want these notes to look like they do in Evernote or when you share them via email (i.e. with formatting, not just text).
One way that looked like it could work would be to share the notes via email, then somehow forward these to my Kindle. However, just auto-forwarding from Gmail won't work because Kindle doesn't look at the content of the email, only attachments. I can't work out how I could best convert the email to something Kindle-friendly. Any ideas would be very welcome!

Comment: What would be the best format for an attachment that Kindle could read?  HTML?  PDF?  Doc?

Comment: I'd say copy the contents from the email to a google doc export as PDF and import to Kindle? Ps I don't see how this is a google apps script question....

Comment: @Sergeinsas Hi Serge, Kindle can deal with: Microsoft Word (.DOC, .DOCX), HTML (.HTML, .HTM), RTF (.RTF), JPEG (.JPEG, .JPG), Kindle Format (.MOBI, .AZW), GIF (.GIF), PNG (.PNG), BMP (.BMP), PDF (.PDF). Also, PDFs can be converted to Kindle format, which is probably best for usability, by emailing to your personal Kindle email with the subject as 'convert'.

Comment: @ThomasvanLatum Sorry Thomas, I didn't make it clear that I'm hoping for an as-automated-as-possible process that doesn't involve me creating a PDF myself (which I could do via Evernote>Print on my Mac) then transferring manually. It'd be good to be able to just click 'share note' (or something similar) and it would appear on my Kindle.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea of how it could work using gmail and docsList services.
In this example I read the first mail of the first thread in your inBox, you should of course play with some kind of filter to get only the threads and mails you want to send to Kindle but this is quite common javascript and easy to setup ...

```
function getBodytoAttach(){ // using 1 variable for each state for clarity...
  var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
  var message = firstThread.getMessages()[0];
  var subject = message.getSubject(); // from that subject you can setup a filter
  var bodystr = message.getBody();//is a string
  var bodydochtml = DocsList.createFile('body.html', bodystr, "text/html");//intermediate doc
  var bodyId=bodydochtml.getId()
  var bodydocpdf = bodydochtml.getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();// get the pdf
  var file_to_send = {fileName: 'body.pdf',content:bodydocpdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
  MailApp.sendEmail('theKindleMailAdress', 'convert', 'see attachment', {attachments:[file_to_send]});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this service.[en2kindle](http://www.en2kindle.com),it sends items in Evernote or Pokcet to your kindle every day.